# is there anyway to make sticky section without script?

Tags: html, css

i wanna make sticky section without script
so when user reach the #box1 part,
it become sticky and have to scroll right gray background color divs
after scrolling all the grey divs then it goes #box2 part which is normal not sticky.

this below code.. this is sometimes it work like i want
but lots of times it is not working and then go to #box2

where i have to fix?
any help will be so appreciated.
thank you!

```css
body {margin:0;
      padding:0;}

#main_banner {background-color:black;
              width:100%;
              height:400px;}

#mainbanner_text { color:gray;
                   text-align:center;
                   font-size:50px;
                   display:inline-block;
                   width:100%;
                   margin-top:150px;}

#box1 {background-color:black;
       width:100%;
       height:600px;
       display:block;
       overflow-x: hidden;
       }

.box50 {width:50%;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid white;
  box-sizing:border-box; }
        
  #box1_text { color:white;
               text-align:center;
               font-size:30px;}
  
#box50_left {position:sticky;
             top:0;}

.box50_inside_bg { width:100%;
                   height:500px;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
                   top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
  color: #fff;}

#box50_right {position:sticky;
              top:0;}

#box2 { background-color:black;
        width:100%;
        height:900px;}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #c7c7c7; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main_banner">
    <p id="mainbanner_text">Main Banner in here!</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="box1">
    <div class="box50" id="box50_left">
      <p id="box1_text">Some Text in Here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box50" id="box50_right">
      <div class="box50_inside_bg" style="background-color:#c7c7c7"></div>
      <div class="box50_inside_bg" style="background-color:#a6a6a6"></div>
      <div class="box50_inside_bg" style="background-color:#7a7a7a"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="box2">
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: There isn't a way to tie css to scroll distance without javascript.

Comment: Hi! oh.... is it?? thanks for let me know about it! have a great day! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
#box1 {
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
}
```

this will stick your `#box1` when scrolled down.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your help! but when i add that, i can't scroll and go to #box2 :( is there anyway to fix this??? thanks and have a great day! :D